# Schema can't initialize with "Can't find field id ..." exception

Tags: java, tarantool

I need a hand here, it seems I'm getting things wrong.

I'm constantly getting the following after auth:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't find field id customer.accountId

at org.tarantool.TarantoolConnection16Base.schema(TarantoolConnection16Base.java:214)
```

I thought ok, may be there is no meta data because there is no data in the space. So I've added a record with all fields, but the error persists.

So how is it supposed to work? Tarantool records are tuples, where I can store any amount of fields, so I thought fields in the field-mapping are basically an enumeration, where only order counts. Where I'm wrong?

Comment: The stacktrace you included is not very helpful. Can you provide more information?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did u forget space.format? 
The example below set that first field  has name 'id' and type 'num' and the second field has name 'text' and type 'str'

```
space = box.schema.space.create('tester')

box.space.tester:create_index('primary', {type = 'hash', parts = {1, 'NUM'}})

box.space.tester:format{{name='id',type='num'},{name='text',type='str'}}
```